# Не работает программа для архивации данных(работа из пример в книге)

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

Дошел в книге до решения задач, первая программа для примера, это программа архивации данных, ввел в точности как в книге, только пути каталогов изменил, не вышло. Ниже привел код программы, над строками где есть комментарии я разобрался что происходит, там где комментарии заканчиваются, я уже не смог разобраться, гугл не помог. При запуске данного кода, никакого архива не создается, даже ошибки нет в командной строке, просто программа прекращает работу сразу после её запуска.

```
import os
import time

#Откуда копируем
source = ['"D:\Miscellanea\Резервные копии"']

#Куда копируем
target_dir = '"D:\Miscellanea\Programmig\Programming-Python\Python\Project\Backup programm\Backup archive"'

#Название сохраненого архима резервных данных, в формате: 
#путь к резервным данным + // + %Год%Месяц%День%Час%Минута%Секундна + формат файла (.zip)
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'


zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))


if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Архив резервных копий создан в', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛАСЬ')
```

Python v3.8.1,
Windows 7(64) Максимальная

[image: Изображение кода и командной строки №2]
Так же в книге говорят о необходимости установить gnuwin32 и прописать путь в переменную Patch по аналогии того, как прописывали сам питон при установке, так же все прописал, скрин ниже
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Так же переменная Patch, полное значение переменной: `D:\Miscellanea\Programmig\Programming-Python\Python\Scripts\;D:\Miscellanea\Programmig\Programming-Python\Python\;D:\Miscellanea\programmig\Programming Python\Python\Scripts\;D:\Miscellanea\programmig\Programming Python\Python\;D:\Miscellanea\programmig\Python\Python\Scripts\;D:\Miscellanea\programmig\Python\Python\;%PyCharm Community Edition%;D:\Miscellanea\Programmig\Programming-Python\Python\Project\Backup programm;D:\Program\GnuWin32\bin`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

смею предположить что книга называется `AByteofPython`. Тогда

1. Внимательно читаем что там пишут

   > Заметьте, что для имён, содержащих пробелы, необходимо использовать
   > двойные кавычки внутри строки

   У вас как раз путь куда копирую содержит пробел. Надо заменить на

   ```
   target_dir = ['"D:\\Miscellanea\\Резервные копии\\Backup archive"']
   ```
2. Дальше будет ошибка в строчке

   ```
   target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'
   ```

   А именно `can only concatenate list (not "str") to list` Т.к. вы
   складываете строки с листом в котором храните путь куда будите
   копировать. Поэтому надо либо убрать лист и оставить

   ```
   target_dir = '"D:\\Miscellanea\\Резервные копии\\Backup archive"'
   ```

   либо указать элемент листа

   ```
   target = target_dir[0] + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'
   ```

Comment: На счет книги правильно подумали, 1 и 2 каюсь, невнимательность сыграла, исправил по вашему примеру, тем не менее это не привело к какому либо результату, все так же при запуске программы через cmd ничего не происходит, даже ошибок не возникает, скинул второе изображение с результатом.

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко а если запускать `python имя_скрипта.py`

Comment: Попробовал, никакого эффекта

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко проблема явно не в коде. питон то хоть правильно установили? Добавляли в path при установке ?

Comment: Само собой, другие программы что я писал, корректно запускаются

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко скопировал ваш код все запускается. вы явно делаете что-то не так как раньше. Добавьте в вопрос скрин с вашими path

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко что будет если просто прописать `python` в смд ?

Comment: Добавил скрин, если в cmd написать просто Python, выводит версию питона, дату установки и разрядность (32),Я уже перепроверял правильность установки питона таким образом, когда вы задали вопрос про это выше

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко т.е если вы сейчас запустите любой другой скрипт на питоне он отработает?

Comment: Да, первым делом проверил это, когда программа отказалась запускаться

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко т.е если вы вставите вот такой код `import os  
  

cmd = 'notepad1'
  


if os.system(cmd)  == 0:
    print('Архив резервных копий создан в', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛАСЬ')` в этот файл у вас тоже ничего не отработает?

Comment: Не отработало, только что проверил

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко а просто print("Hellow word") вместо всего отработает?

Comment: Я был уверен что отработает, но после того как удалил весь код и вставил  print("Hellow word"), тоже ничего не отработало

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко без понятия в чем проблема) но я думаю если вы запустите весь этот код в каком-нибудь другом файле скрипта все заработает)

Comment: Самое забавное, что старые мои скрипты, которые я скинул в папку с неработающим скриптом, так же адекватно работают, спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 0):

я думаю, что дело в не верном пути:

```
source = ['"D:\\Miscellanea\\Резервные копии"']
```

Путь должен быть типа:

```
#Пример пути в линукс:  
source = ["/Users/reivanstr/Library/Fonts"] # используй только одни ковычки

#Пример пути в виндоус
source = ["С:\Users\reivanstr\Library\Fonts"] # отличие в разделительных знаках
```

Comment: Исправил, не помогло, добавил изображение кода и командной строки в описание вопроса